# Python httpS tor connections

Tags: python, https, tor

I'm trying to request things using TOR, first through HTTP and then HTTPS.

I tried really all python libraries for TOR, and ALL of them has the same proble, the HTTPS connection. 
My problem is not the real communication with HTTPS, is that if i try to get new TOR ip, with HTTP request it refresh the IP address, but non the same with HTTPS ! So, i'm still using the TOR network, but always with the same ip ..

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
import requests
import time
import os

session = requests.session()
# signal TOR for a new connection
session.proxies = {'http':  'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150',
               'https': 'socks5://127.0.0.1:9150'}

def new_connection():
    with Controller.from_port(port = 9151) as controller:


    controller.authenticate(password="####")
        # NUOVA CONNESSIONE
    print 'Trying to connect with new IP...'
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
    time.sleep(5) #5 sec
    print "New connection as "+session.get("http://ipecho.net/plain").text

    response = session.get("https://www.google.it/").text
    print response
```

One more thing .. 
I was using the tor version for OSX, but i can't get the control port for it, so i'm using the Tor Browser (9150) with the control port 9151

Answer (score 0):

When you get a new tor identity, you may still have the same ip address, cuz tor only have certain amount of service You can try something like this:

```
def get_new_tor_ip():
try:
    ip_current = session.get("http://ipecho.net/plain").text
except:
    ip_current = OWN_IP
ip_old = ip_current
socket.socket = OWN_SOCKET
with Controller.from_port(address='127.0.0.1', port=9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()  # optional
    socks.setdefaultproxy(socks.PROXY_TYPE_SOCKS5, "127.0.0.1", 9050)
    socket.socket = socks.socksocket
    while True:
        controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
        try:
            ip_current = str(session.get("http://ipecho.net/plain").text
            if ip_current != (ip_old and OWN_IP):
                break
            sleep_time = random.randint(1, 3)
            time.sleep(sleep_time)
        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using stem library it will handle it for you:

```
from stem import Signal
from stem.control import Controller
with Controller.from_port(port = 9051) as controller:
    controller.authenticate()
    controller.signal(Signal.NEWNYM)
```

if you didn't set any hashed password for tor you can remove `controller.authenticate()`.
if you want to set password for tor controller port do as below:

```
tor --hash-password my_password
```

it will generate something like this string `16:3F347B435567CBE1608384B9236897C7322A8EB241CFE5855863F32FB9`. now modify torrc file:

```
sudo vim /etc/tor/torrc
```

uncomment these lines:

```
ControlPort 9051
HashedControlPassword 16:E600ADC1B52C80BB6022A0E999A7734571A451EB6AE50FED489B72E3DF
CookieAuthentication 1
```